# Give Ubuntu more space

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I just installed ubuntu Gnome, made a 20gb partition before installing but somehow there are now 2 partitions and only the one with 5gb gets used by Ubuntu how can I give ubuntu more space in this case?[Screenshot Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqVZ2.png)[Screenshot Ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvyKl.jpg)
I have already check other threats, they said I am supposed to shrink the volume first, but I think I can't shrink it because it's already out of space.
With best regards

Answer (score 0):

Start a live session from a DVD/CD/USB and then:

1. Reduce the swap partition /dev/sdb6
2. Now you have extra space
3. Expand the ext4 / partition /dev/sdb5